error: Failed to initialize NSS library when using yum
i am currently using a centos 7 system, i am aware it's out dated however it will be changed at somepoint, in the mean time whilst doing some maint checks, i did a yum update -y, my ssh then crashed and disconnect me, ever since yum, and rpm both keeps showing
error: Failed to initialize NSS library
There was a problem importing one of the Python modules
required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was:

   cannot import name ts

Please install a package which provides this module, or
verify that the module is installed correctly.

It's possible that the above module doesn't match the
current version of Python, which is:
2.7.5 (default, Apr  2 2020, 13:16:51)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)]

If you cannot solve this problem yourself, please go to
the yum faq at:
  http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/Faq

i am aware there is loads of topics about this but seams every topic i have read has not helped me any way. any support in resolving this would be a big help
the results of /etc/os-release is below
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="7"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:7"
HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"

CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-7"
CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="7"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7"


Questions should demonstrate reasonable information technology management practices. Questions that relate to unsupported hardware or software platforms or unmaintained environments may not be suitable for Server Fault.

CentOS 7 has been EOL since June 30th 2024. With that being said, the error indicates that there is an issue with Python not having that module as yum is written in Python. Either there is a different release of Python in root's PATH that doesn't have that module or the required version or something is causing it to malfunction.
